# Sending a complex object as a parameter in Resteasy

Tags: resteasy

I am using resteasy, and till now I am just sending and receiving string as parameters and every thing was OK, but now I want to send a complex object ( `List<Map<String, ObjectVal>>` ) as one of my parameters. My objectVal class has two simple field ( id and value, with getters and setters).

I can find different question and answers for sending objects as parameters  but all of them are missing something and not useful for me.

here is my functions with a simple string parameter

```
  @GET
    @Path("/isUserAuthorizedToDocument")
        public Response isUserAuthorizedToDocumentService(
            @QueryParam("userID") String userID){
                  .............
                  .............
}
```

and the client

```
private ClientRequest req =new ClientRequest(....url with path and ....)
req.queryParameter("userID", user.getUserId());
ClientResponse<Boolean> response = req.get(Boolean.class);
```

Now I want to send a parameter from my client in the form of `List<Map<String,ObjectVal>>` and recieve it in my rest function.
My ObjectVal class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "objectValueDTO")
public class ObjectValueDTO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Id for this class  
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 164186789404269392L;


    // Id on object type
    private String objectTypeID = "";       
    // Selection
    private String value = "";


    /** Getter and Setters */
    @XmlElement
    public String getObjectTypeID() {
        return objectTypeID;
    }

    public void setObjectTypeID(String objectTypeID) {
        this.objectTypeID = objectTypeID;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }



}
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I may be niave on this. But when you have to send complex parameters, you need to use PUT and send the parameters in the request.